# Quick question on Flex/Action Script - Excessive imports

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I play around a lot when I'm programming in FLEX, mostly cause I'm new and I don't know the best way to do things. Consequently I end up importing a lot of things. I end up throwing out the code and realize later that the imported class is still at the top of my script. Now I have a ton of them. Is there a quick and easy way to see which ones are still being used?

Thanks,

~Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ctrl + shift + o   will clean all unnecessary imports ( in eclipse )

Comment: This is best way. But if You don't use Flex Builder you can try removing them one by one and looking for building errors. Any way unused imports are ugly but not (very) danger.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Flex Builder, you can go to Source -> Organize Imports and it will remove anything you don't need.